# How do I iterate over the HTML attributes of a Beautiful Soup element?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How do I iterate over the HTML attributes of a Beautiful Soup element?

Like, given:

```
<foo bar="asdf" blah="123">xyz</foo>
```

I want "bar" and "blah".

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
page = BeautifulSoup('<foo bar="asdf" blah="123">xyz</foo>')
for attr, value in page.find('foo').attrs:
    print attr, "=", value

# Prints:
# bar = asdf
# blah = 123
```

Comment: How would I go about getting the 'xyz' using the same technique you show here?

Comment: @Clip `page.find('foo').text`