# python extracting HTML tag attributes without regular expressions

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

Is there any way using `urlib`,  `urllib2` or `BeautifulSoup` to extract HTML tag attributes?

for example:

```
<a href="xyz" title="xyz">xyz</a>
```

gets `href=xyz, title=xyz`

There is another thread talking about using [regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317053/regular-expression-for-extracting-tag-attributes)

Thanks

Comment: The docs of BeautifulSoup which you mention cover this quite thorooughly.  If there's some specific aspect you're having trouble with, then you need to be more specific in your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I iterate over the HTML attributes of a Beautiful Soup element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822571/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-html-attributes-of-a-beautiful-soup-element)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML, and for each `<a>` tag, use `tag.attrs` to read the attributes:

```
In [111]: soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup('<a href="xyz" title="xyz">xyz</a>')

In [112]: [tag.attrs for tag in soup.findAll('a')]
Out[112]: [[(u'href', u'xyz'), (u'title', u'xyz')]]
```

Answer (score 6):

why don't you try with the HTMLParser module?

Something like this:

```
import HTMLParser
import urllib

class parseTitle(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'a':
            for names, values in attrs:
                if name == 'href':
                    print value # or the code you need.
                if name == 'title':
                    print value # or the code you need.



aparser = parseTitle()
u = urllib.open('http://stackoverflow.com') # change the address as you like
aparser.feed(u.read())
```