# How can I extract data from within the brackets of `onclick` attribute values?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to extract data from within `onclick` attribute values like `analysis(1644983)`, `AsianOdds(1644983)` and `EuropeOdds(1644983)`? I just want to show one number, as all are same within this HTML code.

**HTML**

```
<td style="word-spacing:-3px" align="left"> <a href="javascript:" onclick="analysis(1644983)">析</a><a href="javascript:" onclick="AsianOdds(1644983)" style="margin-left:3px;">亚</a> <a href="javascript:" onclick="EuropeOdds(1644983)" style="margin-left:3px;">欧</a></td>
```

**Python Code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup=BeautifulSoup("""<td style="word-spacing:-3px" align="left"> <a href="javascript:" onclick="analysis(1644983)">析</a><a href="javascript:" onclick="AsianOdds(1644983)" style="margin-left:3px;">亚</a> <a href="javascript:" onclick="EuropeOdds(1644983)" style="margin-left:3px;">欧</a></td>""",'html.parser')

lines=soup.find_all('onclick')
for line in lines:
    print(line['analysis'])
```

**Expected output**

```
1644983
```

Comment: dear, sorry, I rephrase my question.

Comment: dear, and my question have some difference, I want to get the data from tag and within bracket ()

Comment: sorry, dear, ok let me try !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I iterate over the HTML attributes of a Beautiful Soup element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822571/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-html-attributes-of-a-beautiful-soup-element)

Comment: Not really dear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to explain everything in the comments:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<td style="word-spacing:-3px" align="left">
    <a href="javascript:" onclick="analysis(1644983)">析</a>
    <a href="javascript:" onclick="AsianOdds(1644983)" style="margin-left:3px;">亚</a>
    <a href="javascript:" onclick="EuropeOdds(1644983)" style="margin-left:3px;">欧</a>
    </td>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Find all <a> elements
elements = soup.find_all('a')

# Loop over all found elements
for element in elements:
    # Disregard element if it doesn't contain onclick attribute
    if 'onclick' not in element.attrs:
        continue
    # Get attribute value
    value = element['onclick']
    # Disregard wrong elements
    if not value.startswith('analysis('):
        continue
    # Extract position of opening bracket
    position = value.index('(') + 1
    # Slice string so only content inside bracket is left
    value = value[position:-1]
    # Print result
    print(value)
```

Comment: @Jayjayyy is there a way to make this extraction of arguments in functions passed on attributes of a tag? In other words insted of checking that it starts with `"analysis("`, look if there is a function in general?